# Why are instances created from inherited functions different from instances created by parent functions?

Tags: javascript, oop, prototype

Why are objects created from 'downstream' functions different from objects created from 'upstream' functions ?

If you create a constructor function that inherits from Javascript's Array constructor function, then you'd expect that objects created from your constructor function and the Array constructor function to be the same.

Why are objects not the same in this case ?

I have tried to set NewArray.prototype.constructor to Array but it still gave me the same results.

```
function NewArray() {};
NewArray.prototype = Object.create(Object.getPrototypeOf([]));
NewArray.prototype.constructor = NewArray;
NewArray.prototype.first = function() {
         return this[0];
}
let newArr = new NewArray();
let oldArr = new Array();

newArr.push(5) // {'0': 5, length: 1}; shouldn't it output [5] ???
oldArr.push(5) // [5]
```

Comment: return value of `push` function is the new length of the array after the new element has been pushed ... why would you expect something else if you haven't changed that  behaviour?

Comment: *"shouldn't it output [5]?"* – Well… should *what* output [5]? If you're talking about the browser's console, it will visualise values in all sorts of convenient ways. There's no specification for how something *should* appear in the console. It probably has a special rule for `Array` instances specifically, but other custom objects are output as objects.

Answer (score 0):

This will probably do what you want.

```
function NewArray(){
  Array.call(this);
}

NewArray.prototype = Object.create(Array.prototype);

let z = new NewArray();
z.push(5) // [5]
```

The explanation I know is a bit long and I have less time to type it but taking [Udacity's Object-Oriented JavaScript](https://classroom.udacity.com/courses/ud015) can help clear the confusion (Its a free course).